# Why SQL Server arcgis table data is not update when arcgis rest update data?

Tags: arcgis

Arcgis server version 10.2, we try to get arcgis data directly from SQL Server, before we have been through arcgis provided by the rest interface call.

However, as the number of data gradually increased from 1600 to 6000, we found that the response data became very slow.

So I tried to connect directly to the table inside SQL Server to get data, which successfully solved the problem of slow data receiving.

Strangely, in our 10 experiments, we modified and queried the data through the ArcGIS REST interface, and all showed success without any problems.But the table inside SQL Server where the layer details are stored, has only been modified in real time once.

We began to wonder if ArcGIS REST has a caching mechanism that caches the user's data out of sync with the changes in the database.However, the problem that SQL Server data does not change after arcgis rest modification cannot be solved up to now

Comment: You should check the VIEW table, rather than the basic table.
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129983/edit-default-version-table-view-using-sql-server

Comment: yes we final did it.

Answer (score 0):

We directly call the relevant views in SQL Server in ArcGIS to solve the problem that ArcGIS REST is too slow to query interface data after adding interface call in ArcGIS REST.
1: Because the database query itself is fast.
2. We started to solve the problem of slow data query, but found the original table instead of the view. The real-time interface data of the service provided by ArcGIS REST is stored in the view for calling.This is the crux of the matter.